# Proving that the following is a convex subset

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

It is given that $I(S)=\{z|\exists x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,y,z)^t \in S$}$\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

How do I show that I(S) is a convex subset?

We know that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is already a convex subset.

I know the definition of a convex subset, which I have from Wikipedia. How do I proceed?

Comment: $I(x,y,z)=z$ is an affine function, hence, $I(S)$ is convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\mathrm{p,q\in I(S)}.$ Pick $\mathrm{t}\in[0,1]$.
$$\mathrm{
\exists x_p,y_p,x_q,y_q:(x_p,y_p,p)^\top,(x_q,y_q,q)^\top\in S
}$$
As $\mathrm S$ is convex,
$$\mathrm{
t(x_p,y_p,p)^\top+(1-t)(x_q,y_q,q)^\top\in S\\
\implies(\;\underbrace{tx_p+(1-t)x_q}_x,\;\;\underbrace{ty_p+(1-t)y_q}_y,\;tp+(1-t)q\;)^\top\in S
}$$
So $$\mathrm{\exists(x,y):(\;x,\;y,\;tp+(1-t)p\;)^\top\in S\\
\implies tp+(1-t)q\in I(S)}$$
As $\mathrm{p,q}$ were  chosen arbitrarily in $\mathrm I(S)$ and $\mathrm t$ was chosen arbitrarily in $[0,1]$ this shows that $\mathrm{I(S)}$ is convex.